# how to apply jquery hover for multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery object being passed to my function. In the function I get to one of the sibling. Now how do I apply the .hover to both the objects in one call.

Thanks

Comment: Could we see what you have so far?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure I know exactly what you want to achieve, but something like this?

```
myObject.siblings('selector').andSelf().addClass('hover');
```

The selector depends on how you want to find your sibling. You may want to use something like `next('selector')` or `prev('selector')`, rather than `siblings()`.

**Update**
If the second object is not something that can be chained off of the first object, by a simple selector (which you *should* be able to do if it's a sibling), there's a more general solution.

```
var jq1 = $('any set of elements');
var jq2 = $('any other set of elements');

var all = jq1.add(jq2);
```

This way, regardless of how you find `jq1` or `jq2`, they'll be combined into the variable `all`. From here you can do

```
all.addClass('hover');
```

or

```
all.click();
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/27mPL/)

Comment: the question is if I have different elements which I picked using different jquery selector(can not combine them in one selector,like the one I have where in it is the jquery object that is being passed + the sibiling with some class..which I can pick using class selector ..I want to call once the hover event). Can I put them in an array and apply .hover/any event (click etc) with just one call like [$jq1,$jq2].hover(func1,func2)

Comment: @coool: alright, see my update, I think that should address your problem.

Comment: thanks for responding so quick ..I haven't tired what you put..but it certainly is what I want ..the add method and all.click()..cheers